# Using SetThreadAffinityMask function imported from kernel32.dll

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to set thread affinity using `SetThreadAffinityMask` function imported from kernel32.dll in C# code of mine.

This is how I import it:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]  
static extern IntPtr SetThreadAffinityMask(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr dwThreadAffinityMask);
```

I am creating 3 threads

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(some delegate);
Thread t2 = new Thread(some delegate);
Thread t3 = new Thread(some delegate);
```

I wish to set thread affinity for t1, t2 an t3 for which I am using `SetThreadAffinityMask  function.

But I am not getting how to pass parameters to this function.

`SetThreadAffinityMask` takes two parameters

1. `HANDLE hThread`
2. `DWORD_PTR dwThreadAffinityMask`

Please help me in using `SetThreadAffinityMask`  function in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Don't.

Managed threads <> native threads.

The only option supported for managed threads is to call Thread.BeginThreadAffinity/EndThreadAffinity around code which requires thread affinity.

Comment: Actually the CLR maps managed thread to native thread, but that's an implementation detail that may change.

Comment: CLR inside SQL server doesn't. So that's an implementation detail that even today isn't necessarily true

Comment: Good point. I guess I was being too focused on the plain vanilla CLR.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use [Thread.BeginThreadAffinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should be sure that your .NET thread runs on a particular operating system thread. Wrap the logic with `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity();` and `Thread.EndThreadAffinity();` to do that.

Use `GetCurrentThread()` from `kernel32.dll` to get current thread handle.

Thread affinity mask `dwThreadAffinityMask` described in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247(v=vs.85).aspx):

> A thread affinity mask is a bit vector in which each bit represents a logical processor that a thread is allowed to run on. is allowed to run on.

e.g. if you want to run your thread on the second and fourth logical processors use `0x0A` mask.

Code sample:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetThreadAffinityMask(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr dwThreadAffinityMask);

Thread t1 
  = new Thread(() => 
  {
    try
    {
      Thread.BeginThreadAffinity();
      SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), new IntPtr(0x0A));

      // <your thread logic here>          
    }
    finally
    {
      Thread.EndThreadAffinity();
    } 
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an example on using this function [here](http://khason.net/blog/parallel-programming-well-it%E2%80%99s-all-about-cpu-affinity-or-how-to-set-processor-affinity-in-wpf/).