# Why I can't get the ProcessorAffinity of a thread?

Tags: c#, process, cpu, affinity

I'm making a program for CPU usage statistics. I have a list of [Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netstandard-2.0), each one with its [Process.Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processthread?view=netstandard-2.0). For each thread, I want to know its current affinity to know which CPU Core it is binded to, but [ProcessThread.ProcessAffinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity?view=netstandard-2.0#System_Diagnostics_ProcessThread_ProcessorAffinity) can only be set... not read!

Why? Is there a way to get this information?

Moreover, can I get it without calling low-level Win32 functions but just .NET Standards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SetThreadAffinityMask function imported from kernel32.dll in C # code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498501/using-setthreadaffinitymask-function-imported-from-kernel32-dll-in-c-code)

Comment: @OlivierRogier I don't think so, that question is on how to set, not get.

Comment: Yes, it is about Set. It says that it is impossible in C# for system processes, if I understood. Only for a current app thread. Don't know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the hint by @oliver-rogier, I've managed to do it by using the function to Set the mask (imported from C++). As explained in the docs:

> Return value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is the thread's previous affinity mask.

```
[DllImport(@"kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetThreadAffinityMask(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr dwThreadAffinityMask);


public static IntPtr GetThreadAffinityMask(uint threadId)
{
    Thread.BeginThreadAffinity();

    // get the handle
    IntPtr hThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SET_INFORMATION | ThreadAccess.QUERY_INFORMATION, false, threadId);
    if (hThread == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        var err = GetLastError();
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    // there is no "get" for affinity mask, but the "set" function returns the mask before the operation
    // so first set a temp mask to obtain the current one
    IntPtr old = SetThreadAffinityMask(hThread, new IntPtr((int)Math.Pow(2, Environment.ProcessorCount)) - 1);
    if (old == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        var err = GetLastError();
        return old;
    }

    // then restore the original value
    SetThreadAffinityMask(hThread, old);

    CloseHandle(hThread);
    Thread.EndThreadAffinity();

    return old;
}
```